# How to detect if a CStatic text too long?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I set a `CStatic` as `StringTrimmingEllipsisCharacter`, and I want to show a tooltip when the text is longer than CStatic's length. So I have to detect whether the `CStatic` shows ellipsis. When I use `GetWindowText` it return total text but not text with ellipsis.

I also tried `CDC::GetTextExtent(CString)`, but the width it returned is longer than the text really is.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to detect whether the CStatic's text is too long?

Comment: There is no trivial way to determine whether a [static control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-controls) displays ellipses, there is no such notification or message querying its status. Therefore you should rather check if the text fits into the control - which you attempted to, but didn't work. Maybe you are doing something wrong. A lot of trial and error, if you want to be accurate - a pixel or two can make a difference. Don't know if it's worth, is always displaying the tip unacceptable?

Comment: Rather than trying to find out whether any given text fits a particular display area (which, in general, you cannot), consider using an [in-place tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/implement-in-place-tooltips). Properly positioned, it won't cause a lot of visual noise in case it need not strictly be displayed, i.e. the text fits as-is, but still shows the full text when text is clipped/truncated.

Comment: Also, did you make sure the font matched when you tried the calcs?

Comment: If using CDC::GetTextExtent() mind to first select the real font into the DC as otherwise it might use a default font, which is not the one used in the static control.